# Java CompareTo not returning good results

Tags: java, string, compare

I've implemented a function to check if one url is newer that the other one, in order to go through whole website ex: page1, page2, page3.

But when i'm using compareTo function in Java it doesn't return good result in some case check it out and Please help!

```
String someString1 = "http://view-inventory.aspx?_page=9";
String someString2 = "http://view-inventory.aspx?_page=11";

int comparisonResult = someString2.compareTo(someString1);

System.out.println("Comparison result:"+comparisonResult);


if(comparisonResult==0){
    System.out.println("We're equal");
}
else if(comparisonResult>0){
    System.out.println("Some one is bigger");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Some one is smaller");
}
```

when i compare page=8 and page=9 it works fine but for example above(page=9 and page=10) it doesn't work :(

Comment: Why do you mean by doesn't work ?

Comment: [Lexicographic ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)... (Strikes Again)

Answer (score 1):

That is because `1` (the first digit of `11`) is smaller than `9`. If you use `09` and `11` it will work. In order to make it work, extract the number and compare the number by comparing integers, instead of characters.

Answer (score 0):

That is because 9 is bigger than 1.

You need to substring the part after "=" and cast it to int, then compare.

Answer (score 0):

Simple stuff. 9 > 1. 
Parse the URL until =.
Cast that char to Int.
Then, do the same thing. you'd get your desired output!